# string validation using freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a text like this "please list TK 3-ASDFGVB"

I need to validate this text using freemarker with following scenarios.

```
   - In text make sure , After TK "3-ASDFGVB" should present.
   - "3-ASDFGVB" should contain total 9 character.
   - "3-ASDFGVB" make sure "-" present between 3 and ASDFGVB
```

Tried the scenario's with below code.

```
TKNumberstr="please list TK 3-ASDFGVB"

{TKNumberstr.value?matches('.*([0-3]-[0-9]{9}).*')?then('match','nomatch')}
```

If the validation match then i will continue with next process. Need help to validate the rule

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
<#assign text = "please list TK 3-ASDFGVB" >
<#assign targets = text?split("TK ") , target = targets[1]>

${(target?length == 9 && target?index_of("-")==1)?then('match','nomatch')}
```

You should get `match` as output.

Edit: as per comment below:

```
${((TKNumberstr?split("TK ")[1])?length== 9 && TKNumberstr?split("TK ")[1]?index_of("-")==1)?then('match','nomatch')}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add these into single line, I mean  ```{TKNumberstr.value?matches('.*([0-3]-[0-9]{9}).*')?then('match','nomatch')}```

Comment: @Vijay I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify in the question?

Comment: My question is in a single line can we adapt  the three lines which you  mentioned in your answer. (I.e . ${TKNumberstr.value?matches('.*([0-3]-[0-9]{9}).*')?(length == 9 &&  target?index_of("-")==1)?then('match','nomatch') like this.

Comment: @Vijay I think I understand what you mean. See edit and let me know.